# Load speed of " Gradle : resolve dependencies 'app: debug_compile'" is very slow

Tags: android

[image]

Load speed of  " Gradle : resolve dependencies 'app: debug_compile'"  is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

I feel my answer isn't exactly an answer however I think it's the best you're going to get. 
 This is dependent on the machine you're working with. 
I have found that on different machines this process duration varies greatly. 
 I would suggest you load your project on another machine just to make sure that this is the problem and if it is then you can decide for yourself whether to upgrade or just deal with it.
 Android Studio can be very slow on older machines.